# change user password linux instead of NIS password

Tags: passwords

I'm trying to change password to login on remote server.
For example from pas1 to pas2.

I use passwd command. The result is successful: I see "The NIS password has been changed" and if I try passwd command one more time the pas2 is accepted as old password for passwd command. 
But, when I try to relogin I has to use pas1.

How to change the login password?

Comment: What is the exact command your using?  the command takes some arguments mainly the username the password belongs to.

Comment: Could be a straight UNIX server too, they tend to behave a bit differently with the `passwd` command. Do you know what the server is running (beyond just linux)?

Comment: Ramhound, "passwd"

Comment: Type `alias passwd` to see whether you’re maybe running something other than `passwd`.  Then type `ls –l /bin/passwd` to see whether it’s a symbolic link to something.